# Django: How do I delete one Address instance out of many based on current user using APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an `Address` model which can have multiple instances per user. I am using `APIView` to **delete** one out of many instances but I can't figure out how do i chose the one instance for the logged in user.

My view:

```
class AddressView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    
    def post(self, request):
        ...

    def put(self, request):
        ...

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ...

    def delete(self, request, format = None):
        id = request.GET.get('id', '')
        address = get_object_or_404(Address, id = id)
        address.delete()
        return Response({"message": "Address has been deleted."})
```

I have defined a plain URL that handles `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` along with this `DELETE`:

```
path('address/', AddressView.as_view(), name='user_address'),
```

I understand it has many flaws but every time I run this, I get this error: `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.`

How should be the right view to delete an `Address` instance for the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs a `pk` parameter:

```
path('address/<int:pk>/', AddressView.as_view(), name='user_address'),
```

Modify the `DELETE` method in he view so that it receives the `pk`:

```
def delete(self, request, pk):
    address = get_object_or_404(Address.objects.all(), pk=pk)
    address.delete()
    return Response({"message": "Address has been deleted."})
```